# Error in populating Json Array data into the material UI React table

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-table

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
 const useStyles = makeStyles({
   root: {
     width: '100%',
     overflowX: 'auto',
   },
   table: {
    minWidth: 650,
   },
 });
function createData(data1, data2, data3) {
return {data1, data2, data3, };
}
export default function SimpleTable(props) {
let rowval= props.values;
let rows = createData(rowval)
const classes = useStyles();
return (
  <Paper className={classes.root}>
    <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="simple table">
      <TableHead>
        <TableRow>
          <TableCell>data1</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">data2</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">data3</TableCell>
      </TableRow>
      </TableHead>
      <TableBody>
        {rows.map(row => (
          <TableRow key={row.data1}>
            <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
              {row.data1}
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">{row.data2}</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">{row.data3}</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
         ))}
      </TableBody>
    </Table>
  </Paper>
);
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
react-dom.development.js?61bb:21810 The above error occurred in the <SimpleTable> component:
    in SimpleTable (created by Search)
    in div (created by Search)
    in Search (created by App)
    in div (created by App)
    in App
```

I like to know how to achieve this any references would be appreciated and please find the sample dynamic from api data for the props.values 
 from child component
values 0: [1,2,3], 1:[1,2,5], 2: [1,2,2]

Comment: You posted the stack trace of the error, what is the actual error message?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `createData` function accepts 3 separate parameters, but you're calling it with `rowVal` as an argument, which is coming from `props.values`, which I'm assuming is an Array?

In which case you're calling a function meant for 3 separate strings/number arguments with one array, and then trying to access object properties that don't exist in your JSX, if it's even getting that far, since I'm not exactly sure what destructuring an array as an object key would do.

What are the values in your `values` prop?

**EDIT:** To convert your array of arrays in `values` to an array of objects, you want to iterate over each array and return an object from it.  You already have a function that converts the values into an object.  You can apply it to each of the arrays like so:

```
const createData = (data1, data2, data3) => {
    return { data1, data2, dat3}
}


const rows = props.values.map((arr) => createData(...arr))
```

This will spread all 3 of the array's values as arguments into the function.

Comment: Hello Chris, these are the values contain in  the rowval  which coming from props.values                                                                                                          values                                                                                                                              0: [1,2,3],                                                                                                                          1:[1,2,5] ,                                                                                                                     2: [1,2,2]

Comment: I'm still not clear on whether this is an object full of arrays or an array full of arrays?

Comment: this is array full of array . i am able to access the each field with 
     console.log(rowval[0][0])

Comment: I updated my answer with an example of how you can convert the arrays into objects.

Comment: when i tried to map my array of array values to rows . i am getting this error.              props.values.map is not a function